Nginx Dockerfile unable to find dist folder in MERN app
I have a MERN app. I created the frontend using react with vite. It's build directory is supposed to be frontend/dist. I have Dockerfiles for Nginx, the frontend and backend. I'm using docker compose to start all the containers. When i dockercompose up i get the error:
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 4e2eb982-6e1e-4ac6-8a65-72f7ab5160df::sl9uqn95azj1lt7jxf22ooe94: "/rehaish_frontend/dist": not found
I have tried relative and absolute paths
I tried to build the frontend before using docker compose up
The nginx dockerfile just cannot seem to find the directory
This is my nginx dockerfile:
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY ../rehaish_frontend/dist /usr/share/nginx/html  

EXPOSE 80
# Start NGINX
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


You can't ever COPY ../anything from a parent or sibling directory.  This Dockerfile needs to be moved up to its parent directory and the paths adjusted accordingly.  (You do not need to repeat the last two lines from the base image.)  Also see How to include files outside of Docker's build context?
